# Выдает ошибку java.io.IOexception: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android-studio

```
try {

            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            String Foldertosave = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getPath();
            File file= new File(Foldertosave);
            file.mkdir();
            File file2 = new File(Foldertosave, "1.pdf");
            file2.createNewFile();


            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }


            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();


            input = connection.getInputStream();


           output = new FileOutputStream(file2);
```

Comment: А что в манифесте?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: Гугл говорит что не хватает <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja С ним пробовал уже. Не помогает.

Comment: Значит пытаетесь писать туда, куда нельзя.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Да вроде все туда записываю.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя писать прямо в `Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()`
Нужно создать там папку для себя.

И разрешение, возможно тоже потребуется.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: `String Foldertosave = Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getPath();
                File file= new File(Foldertosave,"testfolder");
                file.mkdir();
                File file2 = new File(file.getPath(), "1.jpg");
                file2.createNewFile();` Пробовал так сделать. Ничего не выходит

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    File.separator + "test1");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();

            }
            File f1 = new File(folder,"2.jpg");
```

Все получилось. Но почему-то не может сохранить в папку `cache`. Получается только на карту памяти. Как сохранить в папку `data`?

**UPDATE**

Решил эту проблему изменив эту строчку.
`output = openFileOutput("filename",MODE_PRIVATE);`